# NoSuchMethodError: eclipse.core.runtime.ListenerList error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently run into this problem when trying to run a application in Windows which was built in Linux. My jdk is 1.8. Can someone suggest me how to fix it

Below is the full log

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.core.runtime.ListenerList.iterator()Ljava/util/Iterator;
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.ChangeManager.fireEvent(ChangeManager.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.value.AbstractObservableValue.fireValueChange(AbstractObservableValue.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.value.WritableValue.doSetValue(WritableValue.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.value.AbstractObservableValue.setValue(AbstractObservableValue.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jface.internal.databinding.viewers.ObservableCollectionContentProvider.setViewer(ObservableCollectionContentProvider.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jface.internal.databinding.viewers.ObservableCollectionContentProvider.inputChanged(ObservableCollectionContentProvider.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jface.databinding.viewers.ObservableListContentProvider$Impl.inputChanged(ObservableListContentProvider.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jface.databinding.viewers.ObservableListContentProvider.inputChanged(ObservableListContentProvider.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1696)
    at com.fk.comprende.views.SituationAnalysisComposite.initDataBindings(SituationAnalysisComposite.java:1847)
    at com.fk.comprende.views.SituationAnalysisComposite.<init>(SituationAnalysisComposite.java:1383)
    at com.fk.ComprendeMapper.createContents(ComprendeMapper.java:362)
    at com.fk.ComprendeMapper$1.run(ComprendeMapper.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at com.fk.ComprendeMapper.open(ComprendeMapper.java:67)
    at com.fk.ComprendeMapper.main(ComprendeMapper.java:55)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of the `org.eclipse.core.runtime` plugin you are using is not compatible with the JFace databinding classes you are using.

Only the version of `org.eclipse.core.runtime` in Eclipse Neon (4.6) or later has the `ListenerList` class with the `iterator` method. Earlier versions of Eclipse have `ListenerList` but it does not have the `iterator` method which your code wants to use.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But my code is written long time ago, there should not be new method in there. Or you mean the code inside my Jface (which is imported in neon) demand newer version of core.runtime

Comment: Well somehow you have ended up using the Eclipse Neon version of `org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable` which uses the new method. Databinding was rewritten for Eclipse Neon.